# What device are bash prompts written to?

Tags: python, bash

I'm not actually trying to get this specific piece of code working, but its output led me to question exactly where prompts are written to. Consider in Python:

```py
subprocess.run("bash", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then I type `fakecommand` and hit enter and then enter EOF. It returns:

```py
CompletedProcess(args='bash', returncode=127, stderr=b'bash: line 2: fakecommand: command not found\n')
```

This does not capture the prompt in `stderr`, but it also does not get printed to the screen as I would expect (nothing like `user@host` shows up).

I know it's extremely wacky to call `bash` in Python. My question is why the prompt does not show up though.

Comment: Prompts are written to stderr, but they won't be written for a noninteractive shell.

Comment: ...and when you don't explicitly specify that you want your shell to be interactive, the determination is made based on whether its output is going to a TTY, which a pipe is not.

Comment: You'll see the same thing if you run `bash 2> >(cat >&2)` at an interactive shell -- stderr isn't a TTY, so no prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unbuffer` to make your copy of bash think stderr is to a TTY, even when it's really going to a FIFO; this will cause it to emit prompts when it would otherwise suppress them.

```
subprocess.run(['unbuffer', 'bash'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that `shell=True` has been removed -- we don't want to start one copy of bash *inside another copy of bash*.

Comment: I know why we shouldn't use `shell=True`; this was simply for convenience's sake at the time of writing the testing code. This code snippet you gave, however, does not really do much. It will print a prompt and you can type some text, but the only way out of it is `Ctrl-C` and nothing is retrievable. Not that I'm really trying to use this code. Was just looking for an answer what's up with the prompts, which you answered in the comments. Thanks. Nevertheless, the behavior I just described is certainly odd and now I'm curious about that, too.

Comment: If there's a specific part of the behavior that's surprising, feel free to ask a question about it.

Comment: Yes. Why does the code you provided print a prompt and you can type some text, but the only way out of it is Ctrl-C and nothing is retrievable?

Comment: I did say _ask a question_. Y'know, _as a question_. :)

Comment: ...it's not clear to me what you mean by "nothing is retrievable". Some of the other aspects I'll want to actually do a sysdig trace to confirm my understanding before answering; the formal ask-a-question process makes it easier to provide a long-form, researched response (and encourages others to fact-check same).